# UPDATE REGEXP_REPLACE не работает

Tags: sql, update, replace, qregexp

Когда мне что-нибудь надо удалить из БД WordPress, то помогает запрос для замены подстроки.
new_str я делаю пустым и получается замена старого текста на ничего:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content =
REPLACE (post_content, 'old_str', 'new_str');
```

Но сейчас мне надо удалить списки ul li

```
<ul class="article-random-link-ul">
<li class="article-random-link-li">rand_str</li>
</ul>
```

Составил регулярное выражение, но не работает.

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content =
REPLACE (post_content, '/<ul class="article-random-link-ul"><li class="article-random-link-li">(.)*ul>/g', '');
```

Такой вариант тоже не работает:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content =
REGEXP_REPLACE (post_content, '<ul class="article-random-link-ul"><li class="article-random-link-li">.*ul>', '');
```

Ошибка

> .*ul>', '');

Comment: А кто Вам сказал, что REPLACE() работает с регулярными выражениями? используйте REGEXP_REPLACE(). PS. Речь ведь идёт о MySQL, верно?

Comment: MySQL верно. Сайт на wp

Comment: Вместо REPLACE я пробовал REGEXP_REPLACE, но тоже не работает. Видимо там синтаксис другой.

Comment: Ошибка выскакивает в месте:
>(.)*ul>

Comment: А нафига тут группа? просто `.*`

Comment: Как правильно составить REGEXP_REPLACE для моего случая?

Comment: Ну так сделайте fiddle, или хотя бы выложите CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO (3-5 записей).